# Regular Expressions in a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

Would it be possible to select using a regular expression in jQuery? Something like

```
$('input[name=^[a-z]+_[1-9].*]')
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's nothing built in, but you could use the [*filter()*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to achieve the same goal:

```
$('input').filter(function () { return /^[a-z]+_[1-9].*/.test(this.name); })
```

Comment: +1 - This is cleaner, hope you don't mind - took an extra brace from the question off there

Comment: @Nick: don't mind at all, ta very much :) Teaches me not to just copy and paste blindly lol.

Answer (score 4):

You can find [a regex selector here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) (by James Padolsey), called like this in your case:

```
$('input:regex(name,^[a-z]+_[1-9].*)');
```

Comment: I love the convenience of custom selectors, but often worry about the performance of them.  I haven't checked the code, but I keep meaning to, just to put my mind at ease that they don't put too much extra strain on parsing the whole selector.

Comment: @Andy - It's definitely a valid concern, just depends how much you're using them and how each browser in-lines the calls, the ideal solution without that info would be declaring the regex before just once.